# Что это за синтаксис массива с двойными скобками?

Tags: javascript

Объясните пожалуйста что это за синтаксис массива и как правильно его понимать/читать?

```js
console.log( [0,10,20,30][1] );
console.log( [0,10,20,30][2] );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявляется массив и сразу же берётся элемент этого массива по индексу 1 или 2

Это равнозначно:

```
let arr = [0,10,20,30];
console.log(arr[1]);
console.log(arr[2]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается с объектами аналогично работает `console.log( {a: 0, b: 10, c: 20, d: 30}['c'] );`

Comment: угу... и со строками тоже...))